# Android and Java Static variable Initialization

Tags: android, service, global-variables, static-members

This is my code for service class here previous_network_type is global static variable it is not initialized in oncreate() or onstartcommand() function also not from activity on create function why is that any help?? whenever i used it, it gives me 0 value it should give me 10 after starting of this service but returns 0. To be more clear

First MyService has previous_network_type variable i want to assign it a value in oncreate or oncommand function
which i'l use in another class which is broadcast receiver
and you know that broadcast receiver runs only when an event is occur so what m trying to do whenever a particular event occur i want to access this value

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    static int previous_network_type=0;

    public void onCreate() {
        previous_network_type=10;
    };

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        previous_network_type=10;
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

and the code of other class(Broadcast receiver is given below)

```
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {
    MyService.current_network_type=MyService.previous_network_type;
           }
```

Comment: perhaps the variable needs to be public?
Also, not related to the problem, you have an unneeded semi-colon at the end of on create.

Comment: if your onCreate methods run properly , it must be =10 even if your service destroy except dvm is off.

Comment: it is working properly I checked like 100 times

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         i=new Intent(this,MyService.class);

        startService(i);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();;
        stopService(i);
    }


}



public class MyService extends Service {

    static int previous_network_type=0;

    public void onCreate() {
        previous_network_type=10;
    };

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        previous_network_type=10;
        Log.e("check","Value"+previous_network_type);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

check once if you have defined the Service in Android.manifest.xml

```
  <service android:name="com.example.kuchbhi.MyService"
            ></service>
```

Comment: when i used it outside from this service it gives zero

Comment: for example i need it in broadcast receiver and their it gives 0

Comment: but oncreate and onstartcommand functions called automatically when the service starts

Comment: its global and static why doesnt the value stay in there.

Comment: I told you I am accessing this variable from another class and there it returns zero

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34370/discussion-between-anchit-and-ateeq)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you are accessing the value after the service has been created/started.
**Try to debug.**